# Proving a Theorem About Binary Operations - Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, peano-axioms

I am currently self-studying "The Real Numbers and Real Analysis" by Bloch, and I am having a hard time understanding a particular part of the proof for the following Theorem (my question is at the bottom).

**Theorem 1**: There is a unique binary operation +: $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the following two properties for all n,m $\in\mathbb{N}$

1) $n+1=s(n)$

2) $n+s(m)=s(n+m)$

The following, definitions, axiom, lemma, and theorem can be used to prove this theorem as they came before the theorem.

**Definition**: Let S be a set. A binary operation on S is a function S$\times$S$\rightarrow$S

**Axiom**:There exists a set $\mathbb{N}$ with an element 1 $\in\mathbb{N}$ and a function $s: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy the following three properties.

1) There is no n $\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s(n)=1$

2)The function $s$ is injective

3)Let $G\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be a set. Suppose 1 $\in G$, and that if g $\in G$ then $s(g)\in G$. Then $G=\mathbb{N}$

**Lemma**: suppose $a\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose $a\neq1$, then there is a unique $b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a=s(b)$

**Theorem 2 (Definition by Recursion)**: Let $H$ be a set, let $e\in H$ and let $k: H\rightarrow H$ be a function . Then there is a unique function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow H$ such that $f(1)=e$ and $f(s(n))=k(f(n))$

The following is the beginning of the proof for existence of Theorem 1 given in the book. I have only shown up to where I have problems. I have indicated with quotation marks the part I am having trouble with ( I am not use to mathjax).

Proof: Suppose $p\in\mathbb{N}$. We can apply the Definition by Recursion to the set $\mathbb{N}$,"the element $s(p)\in\mathbb{N}$", and the function $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ to deduce that there is a unique function $f_p:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_p(1)=s(p)$ and $f_p(s(n))=s(f_p(n))$...

Why is $s(p)\in\mathbb{N}$? I do realize the function $s$ is defined as $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, so the output of the function $s$ must be in $\mathbb{N}$, but how do we know $s(p)$ is defined from the above info. The only reason I can think of is we can assume that for any $p$
, $s(p)$ is defined, but I am not convinced because the axiom says that function is only injective, not bijective, and I do not know how to prove its bijective. I do not think I need to prove its bijective because the text doesn't.

Comment: You know $s(p) \in \mathbb{N}$ because the proof begins with "suppose $p \in \mathbb{N}$", so $s$ has the correct input. Then, by the definition of $s$ you know its output, $s(p)$, will be an element of $\mathbb{N}$, as you mentioned.

Comment: @BillWallis but isn't it possible s(p) is not defined at p?

Comment: By definition, $s$ is defined for all $\mathbb{N}$. Since it is explicitly stated that $p\in \mathbb{N}$, $s$ will therefore be defined for all $p$. Had there not been the statement "$p \in \mathbb{N}$" then there may be confusion since we would not know what kind of number $p$ is.

Comment: @BillWallis I'm sorry that I am having a hard time understanding, but where does it say $s$ is defined for all $\mathbb{N}$ or is it something I should just know

Comment: I do not understand part (2) of theorem 1. Should there not be an $m$ on the left side of the equation? The standard way to express (2) is $n+s(m)=s(n+m)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: One of the Peano axioms says that if $p\in\mathbb{N}$ then $s(p)\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: And the reason that $s$ is not bijective is that there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s(n)=1$. The smallest value of $s(n)$ is 2.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Is that part 3) of the axiom? I did not think it was because it seems to me that is only induction, and it is only used to prove a set is equal to $\mathbb{N}$. Also, this was all the info I was given,

Comment: I don't have a copy of Bloch's book so I do not know how he numbered his Peano axioms. In Wikipedia's version that is axiom 6. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms

Comment: @EthanGodden The third axiom is the one that tells you that $s$ is defined for **all** $\mathbb{N}$. It explains it almost inductively - if 1 is in the set $G$, then 1+1=2 is also in $G$, so 2+1=3 is in $G$, and so on... You already know that $s$ maps $\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$ because you wrote $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and axiom three tells you that it is defined on **all** on $\mathbb{N}$. If you're still struggling to understand, try and find some $p$ for which $s(p)$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is $s(p) \in \mathbb{N}$? I do realize the function $s$ is defined as $s:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, so the output of the function $s$ must be in $\mathbb{N}$, but how do we know $s(p)$ is defined from the above info. The only reason I can think of is we can assume that for any $p$ , $s(p)$ is defined, but I am not convinced because the axiom says that function is only injective, not bijective, and I do not know how to prove its bijective. I do not think I need to prove its bijective because the text doesn't.

This has nothing to do with bijectivity. It is simply that $p \in \mathbb{N}$ (by assumption). That is, $p$ is in the domain of $s$. Look at your axiom defining $s$. It states that $s$ is a function whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and whose codomain is $\mathbb{N}$. That means for each $p \in \mathbb{N}$, $s(p) \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you, I previously did not seem to know what bijectivity (or surjectivity) truely meant. I also previously thought that when you defined a function $s: G_1\rightarrow G_2$, where both are arbitrary sets, that it did not imply the function was defined for all elements in $G_1$. Thank You for your help.